# Need to call I18n Javascript, somehow can't

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

In Ruby on Rails, I am inside an AJAX method as follows, where I load data from an array:

```
$(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/areas',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(dat) {
      for (var i = 0; i < dat.length; i++) {
        var d = (data[i] = {});
        d["length_unit"] = dat[i].length_unit;
```

The problem is, what I really need on the right-hand side is I18n.t(dat[i].length_unit)
I have a config/locales/sp.yml file, and the translation isn't found, if I do this.
I've also tried something like this:

```
d["length_unit"] = <%= I18n.t(dat[i].length_unit) %>;
```

but that doesn't work because the variable "dat[i]" isn't found that way.
How can I do the I18n translate on the right-hand-side?

**Additional information.**
On the server, in the index method for areas, I am doing this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render :json => @areas }
end
```

What I really need to do - is render each @area with I18n.t(@area.length_unit), instead of @area.length_unit. In other words, I need to do a little pre-processing before I render, and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Do the translation on the server, i.e. send a translated version of `dat` back.

Comment: @FelixKling, yes, I have thought of that. I was hoping there was a trick for doing it in the AJAX instead.

Comment: You can do another Ajax call, but that does not seem to be a good solution. Since `I18n.t()` appears to be a server side function, it will be called when you request the page and the data you pass to it has to be available on the server at this moment. Mixing languages like you tried does not work, because the code is executing at different times on different machines. You make a request to server which generates an HTML file (with Ruby in your case). The result is then sent back to the client (the browser), where it interprets the HTML and executes the JavaScript.

Comment: @Felix, the <%= %> syntax does work, in other places in the index.html.erb code. I'm in a Javascript section here. You might be right, though- but I'm hoping someone might know a workaround.

Comment: I know that it works. But whatever is inside `<%= %>` is executed when you request the page this code is contained in, not when the Ajax call was successful. Lets call the file `index.html`. Then the order is: *Client:* Request `index.html` -> *Server:* generate `index.html`, process `<%= %>`, return `index.html` -> *Client:* parse HTML, execute JavaScript, make Ajax call -> *Sever:* generate Ajax response -> *Client:* process response (`dat`). Do you see that you tried to somehow mix the third with the last step, which occur at two different moments in time at different locations?

Comment: As a simple example, put `<%= 42 %>;` instead of the function call and have a look at the **generated** HTML (right click -> view page source). It should look like `d["length_unit"] = 42;` which shows that at the moment the JavaScript is executed, the `<%= %>` don't exist anymore. It is really important to understand how the whole web page request life cycle works.

Comment: @FelixKling, I am very grateful for this explanation. This is giving me a lot more to think about - I always do better with a full explanation. I would be OK to do it on the server, except I need to understand something. I will add it to the post; if you could take a look, I would be grateful.